# BadRequestException while putting POJO containing ByteBuffer in Invocation.Builder.post in jax-rs?

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly

I'm trying to post a POJO entity like below in Arquillian test class.

```
MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
pojo.setBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap("Happy new year".getBytes()); //this is the problem
pojo.setOtherFiled(someotherfield)

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(url).request(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

MyPojo response = builder.post(Entity.json(pojo), MyPojo.class);
```

My rest resource end point looks like this

```
 MyPojo myEndPoint(MyPojo pojoParam){
     //the body is immaterial since it's not going inside the body.
 }
```

I'm getting `javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException:HTTP 400 Bad Request`.

If I comment out `pojo.setBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap("Happy new year".getBytes());`, it's not giving that error.

What is the problem with the above code how to correct it?

Comment: Does the String have to be a ByteBuffer?  What happens if you use a String instead?  I suspect Entity.json doesn't know how to encode ByteBuffers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The instance variable is of type `ByteBuffer` inside `MyPojo`, so I should send as byte buffer. Actually this is a minified version of my original code which replicates the problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey when I used some other data type instead of ByteBuffer such as byte array it's working. we're using jackson. is that a problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do _you_ expect the `ByteBuffer` to be represented in JSON?

Comment: @peeskillet that's a point. At the resource end point I'm not concerned with the json representation but with MyPojo representation. It's seamless.

Comment: Is the field value always going to be a String or is it just arbitrary binary data?

Comment: It's actually a `Map<String, List<Object>>` object which is converted into bytes using `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` then calling  `ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray()` then I would wrap it using `ByteBuffer#wrap()`. To simplify matters, I've given a String in the above example and converting them to bytes.

Comment: Have you tried just sending it as is? I would imagine Jackson should be able to marshal that. Maybe I'm just not understanding why the need to convert to ByteBuffer

Comment: Because we are using `cassandra` database and one of the column's data type is `blob` and the java type for it is ByteBuffer. So that map representation is encoded as blob in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out why it's happening. The `Jackson` cannot serialize `ByteBuffer` as it is an abstract class. It's not straight forward it might need additional type information.

At the client end we send the `json`(jackson serializes the `POJO`) but when reconstructing the `POJO` class before passing to the `rest` end point, it fails to reconstruct the object of the POJO class from json as it doesn't know how to create a `ByteBuffer` instance.

I figured it by trying to use `jackson` to serialize and de-serialize `ByteBuffer` in a stand alone class. It will throw

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.nio.ByteBuffer, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information`

`Jackson` lies in pre-processing phase of the request processing in `Resteasy`. So, `Resteasy` is giving `400 bad request` as it could not process the request.

As a work around I'm using `byte[]` instead of `ByteBuffer` and converting it to `ByteBuffer` instance in the end point.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the JSON Mapper to fasterxml will fix this issue. I have upgraded and the issue is fixed for me.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson